# Simple access authorization with Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Trying to implement simple access authorization with Lumen. It works when doing the update (PUT) action.
But I would also like to handle accessing for example all articles.

I also tried the `viewAny` or `view` policy method but no success.

**Router**

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('articles',  ['uses' => 'ArticleController@showAllArticles']);
    $router->get('articles/{id}', ['uses' => 'ArticleController@showOneArticle']);
    $router->post('articles', ['uses' => 'ArticleController@create']);
    $router->delete('articles/{id}', ['uses' => 'ArticleController@delete']);
    $router->put('articles/{id}', ['uses' => 'ArticleController@update']);
});
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Gate::policy('App\Article', 'App\Policies\ArticlePolicy');

        $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            return app('auth')->setRequest($request)->user();
        });
    }
}
```

**Policies**

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Article;

class ArticlePolicy
{
    public function showAllArticles(User $user, Article $post)
    {
        // not working
        return true;
    }

    public function update(User $user, Article $post)
    {
        // this works
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    public function showAllArticles()
    {
        $this->authorize('showAllArticles');
        return response()->json(Article::all());
    }

    public function showOneArticle($id)
    {
        return response()->json(Article::find($id));
    }


    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize('update', $article);
        $article->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($article, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: how is it supposed to know what `showAllArticles` relates to? it needs to know the model so it can match it to the policy ... also that actual method wouldn't be taking an instance of the model in its definition since you are not passing one

Comment: Not really clear. showAllArticles works passing the data. Authorize is not working. Where should I pass the model for that to work?

Comment: in the authorization docs for policies you will see the text "Actions That Don't Require Models" in numerous places (for calling the gate/policy) to define them to be used that way: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#methods-without-models

Comment: Read the docs of Lumen and Laravel. That's why I'm posting here.

Comment: i linked you to the exact part of how you have to define that method in the policy and also how to actually call this ... it is right there

Comment: In this time it had been much more effective to explaining the functionality on the example I posted above, than pointing to docs that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Laravel documentation on Authorization:

> "When defining policy methods that will not receive a model instance, such as a `create` method, it will not receive a model instance. Instead, you should define the method as **only** expecting the authenticated user:"

```
public function create(User $user)
```

So:

```
public function showAllArticles(User $user)
```

> "As previously discussed, some actions like `create` may not require a model instance. In these situations, you should pass a class name to the `authorize` method. The class name will be used to determine which policy to use when authorizing the action:"

```
$this->authorize('create', Post::class);
```

So:

```
$this->authorize('showAllArticles', Article::class);
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Authorization - Writing Policies - Methods without Models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#methods-without-models)

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Authorization - Authorizing Actions Using Policies - via Controller Helper](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers) `authorize`

No explanation needed.

Comment: Is injecting User and Atricle into showAllArticles method really needed? Nothing is being done with it. 
So all that was needed is to append the Article Class name to the authorize method to determine the right policy. Simple to understand explanation.

Comment: these are not injected, they are passed when called by the gate ... and yes the docs have a very simple explanation of how to handle these things, as i only needed to reference 2 paragraphs

Comment: most likely the misunderstanding is people not linking the fact they may not be passing an instance to `authorize` or the gate in general to what is meant by "methods without models"